# IE7 width:auto issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, width, internet-explorer-7

CSS

```
    #wrapper .tn{
      width:auto;
      height:20px;
      line-height:20px;
      float:left;
      padding:5px 2px 5px 5px;
      margin:0 5px 10px;
      font-weight:bold;
      background:#f0f0f0;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="tn">Text</div>
        <div class="tn">Text</div>
        <div class="tn">Text</div>
    </div>
```

Above codes work smooth in FF,Chrome,Safari,Opera,IE9,IE8 . But there is problem for IE7. Div doesn't expand according to text.It cover wrapper div as width. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems fine to me, checked using IE7 developers tools, you can try `display: inline-block;` instead of `float`

```
#wrapper .tn{
  height:20px;
  line-height:20px;
  padding:5px 2px 5px 5px;
  margin:0 5px 10px;
  font-weight:bold;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the div you're talking about is #wrapper?  #wrapper isn't expanding because you need to clear the floats

Check out the clearfix class in the HTML5 Boilerplate (https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/main.css)

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

So do this in your code:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
    <div class="tn">Text</div>
    <div class="tn">Text</div>
    <div class="tn">Text</div>
</div>
```